# Temp tables disappearing

Tags: sql, ms-access, temp-tables, pass-through

I'm creating a SQL process that begins with setting up a few temp tables in Access with pass-through to SQL Server.

After these temp tables are created, there are two very large queries (query A and Query B) that use these temp tables along with some other linked tables and are themselves also loaded into temp tables.

Query A executes fine but when I run Query B it tells me that the initial temp tables no longer exist. And similarly if I run query B first and then query A, Query A tells me the same thing.

> Ex. "ODBC--call failed. [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Invalid object name '#nbrvariables'. (#208)"

I have to rerun the setup steps first and then whichever query comes second will execute. Why is this happening? Are my tables being dropped in the background for some reason?

Comment: temp tables only persist while you have the connection open.  If you open one, create a temp table, then close out that connection, and connect again it will not be there.  You need to create a permeant table, or a permanent temp table (stays across all sessions till you drop it or server restarts)

Comment: If that's the case though, wouldn't the table drop after the creation query finishes and before the Query A executes?

Comment: Temp tables should be created in frontend. I make them permanent then delete/insert records. Edit question to post your code.

Comment: You really can't much control when the sql server temp tables go away. Worse yet, is you can't link to those temp tables FROM Access. You can only really use the temp table(s) in ONE PT query that could have several lines of t-sql. However, once that PT query is done (finished), then the sql temp tables will ALSO go away. You can't really much with any control in fact control this. So you have to use actual temp tables (either client side (but then no PT query), or have some tables server side - but you have to add a column such as user or some such to distinguish rows for each of the users.